# Extend customer grid using customer_listing.xml issue

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, toolbar, customer-grid

I'm using magento v2.2.5 and i tried to add new column in magento 2 grid by extending customer_listing.xml like this:

```
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
 <columns name="customer_columns" class="Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns">
   <column name="membership" sortOrder="45">
       <settings>
           <filter>text</filter>
           <label translate="true">Membership</label>
       </settings>
   </column>
  </columns>
</listing>
```

the column shows up perfectly, but the problem is the filter toolbar above the grid is dissapear, but when i scroll down the filter toolbar shows up, when i click the filter toolbar the filter didnt appear at top of customer grid but at the bottom:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to truncate table named as **ui_bookmark** then check. Please export this table before you truncate so that you have backup of this table in case anything went wrong.

Comment: Did it work for you @mileven ?